# How to get the count given to a macro?

Tags: macro, count

When executing an ex command I can use the variable `v:count` to get the count which was given to this command. From [`:h v:count`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount), if I create this mapping:

```
:map _x :<C-U>echo "the count is " . v:count<CR>
```

And use <kbd>12</kbd><kbd>_</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> I'll get a message

```
the count is 12
```

**How can I do the same with a macro?**

When calling a macro 12 times with <kbd>12</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> how can I know that the current execution is the *n*th of the 12?

---

So far I tried to create a macro which show the count like like:

```
qaa<C-r>=v:count<CR><Esc>q
```

But when I play it with <kbd>12</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>; I simply get 12 zeros:

```
000000000000
```

Which makes me think that the variable `v:count` is not used by macros.

Comment: As a first comment, the `:h [count]` help gives an insight that repeating a macro is no different than repeating any other command, e.g. `3D`.

Comment: @nobe4 That's what I thought but see my edit, it seems like `v:count` isn't used in a macro.

Comment: You could try remapping `@` so that it takes a char with `getchar`, and then run the text from `getreg`

Comment: @DJMcMayhem that would be a possibility but I'm surprised there is not a built-in way to do so.

Comment: `v:prevcount` would give you the count for that particular macro, but only for the first run. `v:count` is giving you the count for the `a`, not the `@a`.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there is no built-in way to do what I want. So I came up with this small chunk of code following @DjMcMayhem comment. It is not extensively tested but it seems to be working.

First let's remap `@` to call our custom function:

```
nnoremap <silent> @ :<C-U>call MacroWithCount()<CR>
```

And the function:

```
function! MacroWithCount()
    # Get the content of a register given by the user
    let registerContent = getreg(nr2char(getchar()))
    let macroCount = v:count1

    for i in range(macroCount)
        execute "normal! " . registerContent
        let macroCount = macroCount - 1
    endfor
endfunction
```

First we use `getreg()` combined with `getchar()` to get the content of a register given by the user.

Then we create the `macroCount` variable which will be the variable to use in the macro to get the current count.

Finally we execute the macro and update `macroCount` each time the macro has been executed once.

Now if I record this macro:

```
qaa<C-r>=macroCount<CR> <Esc>q
```

I get:

```
 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**Note** that the function still needs a major improvement: it doesn't understand `@@` as `execute the last executed macro`. so far I haven't found a way to get the content of the last executed macro (I thought that it was what `v:register` was for but it seems that I was wrong)

The related help topics:

- [`:h v:count1`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Acount1)
- [`:h getchar()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getchar%28%29)
- [`:h getreg()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#getreg%28%29)
- [`:h v:register`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#v%3Aregister)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but does what you asked :)

```
y3w:exec 'norm!' getreg('"') == "the count is " ? "3w\<c-a>`[3b" : "ithe count is 1\<esc>3b"
```

Save this to register `a` and when you <kbd>12</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> it will print

```
the count is 12
```

Since there is no way to pass the count to the macro (that I know of), the macro is still run `n` times but it will only increment the number after the first run.